# iterate multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that holds 'cell' images used as a cache:

```
/* make a symbol cell image with/without color and save it in the cache */
if(!isset($stitchCache[$r][$g][$b]))
{
  //create new image
  $stitchCache[$r][$g][$b] = imagecreatetruecolor(SYMBOL_SIZE,SYMBOL_SIZE);
  $stitchCacheColor = imagecolorallocate($stitchCache[$r][$g][$b], $r, $g, $b);
  //draw colored rectangle
  imagefilledrectangle($stitchCache[$r][$g][$b], 0, 0, SYMBOL_SIZE-1, SYMBOL_SIZE-1, $stitchCacheColor);
  //add the symbol
  $symbolFile=$stitchChartArray[$y][$x][1];
  if($symbolFile){
    $symbolImage = imagecreatefrompng($symbolFile);
    imagecopyresampled ($stitchCache[$r][$g][$b],$symbolImage,0,0,0,0,SYMBOL_SIZE-1,SYMBOL_SIZE-1,imagesx($symbolImage), imagesy($symbolImage) );
    imagedestroy($symbolImage);
  }
}

//add image from cache to the block image
imagecopyresampled ($newBlockImage,$stitchCache[$r][$g][$b],$stitchStartX, $stitchStartY,0,0,SYMBOL_SIZE,SYMBOL_SIZE,SYMBOL_SIZE,SYMBOL_SIZE);
```

I need to later destroy each image in the array. I came up with this, but it is not correct.

```
//dump stitch cache
foreach($stitchCache as $r)
{
    foreach($stitchCache[$r] as $g)
    {
        foreach($stitchCache[$r][$g] as $b)
        {
            imagedestroy($stitchCache[$r][$g][$b]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you again,
Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just destroy it right after the call to `imagecopyresampled`? Unless you left out code, that's what I would do.

```
foreach($stitchCache as $rk => $r)
{
    foreach($r as $gk => $g)
    {
        foreach($g as $bk => $b)
        {
            imagedestroy($stitchCache[$rk][$gk][$bk]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how I was doing it. The grid I am creating can be pretty large, 150 cells x 150 cells(or more) so each image in the cache could be called 22000 times or more, it cut down my time quite a bit not recreating it each time.

Comment: I am getting this error: Illegal offset type in /Users/tnt/Sites/cross_stitch/beta2/ajax/makeChartPackage.php on line 449
[17-Feb-2012 18:20:15] PHP Warning:  imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Users/tnt/Sites/cross_stitch/beta2/ajax/makeChartPackage.php on line 449

Comment: Updated. If it still doesn't work, pastebin a var_dump of the array please.